# How to make C# application crash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash

I want to test if my application crash dump can be debugged. But firstly, I need to generate a crash dump of my application. I'm using C# to code my app, and have tried with many exceptions and unsafe code etc. but don't get it.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Sorry, Just forgot something, I'm making the application with Unity3D, which handles exceptions for me automatically.

**Edit 2:** Thanks all for your answers. I've tested your suggestions in a standard C# application and it all works fine, but not in my Unity3D application (written with C#). It seems like Unity3D requires more effort to cause a crash, I might email Unity3D to get a answer. I will post here if I get it. Cheers!

Comment: Congrats, you seem to be the most professional programmer!

Comment: how about int x = 0;
         double blah = 5/x;

Comment: object obj = null; obj.ToString();

Comment: A crash simply occurs when an unmanaged exception is thrown at runtime. There's nothing magic behind it. Maybe the problem is that your code isn't working correctly, and that's why you're not having any log.

Comment: What kind of application it is?

Comment: Throw an exception forcefully.

Comment: int[] x = {0};
         int blah = x[2];

Comment: `throw new Exception();`  ... ?

Comment: Partially unseat a DIMM on the motherboard?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134048/generating-net-crash-dumps-automatically

Comment: This seems like a poorly researched question

Answer (score 23):

The following will provide an unhandled exception and will ask for you to choose a debugger:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

Comment: Although the question was a silly one but this answer definitely was the opposite, +1.

Comment: sorry, I try, but get "NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented"

Comment: Since you say you are developing in Unity3D, this might not be an option, sorry...

Answer (score 18):

`StackOverflowException` is a badass:

```
void PerformOverflow()
{
  PerformOverflow();
}
```

Usage:

```
PerformOverflow();
```

Answer (score 12):

Throw an exception :)

```
throw new Exception("Your exception here!");
```

Comment: sorry,I have try throwing an exception, but that doesn't crash my application.

Comment: sorry, I lost something: I use Unity3d, and it handles all exceptions, just show me the exceptions in the output file. thanks

Comment: This is not a CRASH. A crash can only occur from native code that crashes, or calls into RaiseException Win32 API.

Answer (score 11):

For C# in **Unity3D**

There is [**`UnityEngine.Diagnostics.Utils.ForceCrash`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Diagnostics.Utils.ForceCrash.html) (in Unity 2018.3)

This can be used with one of the following [`ForcedCrashCategory`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Diagnostics.ForcedCrashCategory.html) enum parameter:

> **AccessViolation**
>
> Cause a crash by performing an invalid memory
>   access.The invalid memory access is performed on each platform as
>   follows:
>
> **FatalError**
>
> Cause a crash using Unity's native fatal error
>   implementation.
>
> **Abort**
>
> Cause a crash by calling the abort() function.
>
> **PureVirtualFunction**
>
> Cause a crash by calling a pure virtual function
>   to raise an exception.

---

For **older versions** of Unity:

`UnityEngine.Application.ForceCrash(int mode)`

For even older versions (Unity 5):

`UnityEngine.Application.CommitSuicide(int mode)`

From my experience, mode 0 causes a "unity handled" crash (where the Unity crash dialog appears), and mode 2 causes a "hard" crash where the Windows error dialog appears.

This seems consistent with [this post by Smilediver](https://forum.unity.com/threads/application-commitsuicide-int-mode.46495/#post-1697831) on `mode`:

> 0 - will simulate crash, 1 - will simulate a fatal error that Unity
>   has caught, 2 - will call abort().

(These methods are not documented as they were intended for Unity's internal use. They may also be marked `[Obsolete]` depending on your Unity version.)

Answer (score 8):

Well. The only good 100% way actualy crash CLR is to inject a **native** exception into the managed world.

Calling the Kernel32.dll's RaiseException() directly will immediately crash ANY C# application, and Unity Editor as well.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void RaiseException(uint dwExceptionCode, uint dwExceptionFlags,  uint nNumberOfArguments, IntPtr lpArguments);

void start()
{
    RaiseException(13, 0, 0, new IntPtr(1));
}
```

Happy crashing. Please note that in order to debug native **and** managed, you will need two instances of Visual Studio running. If you are developing native P/INVOKE plugin, set up it that Visual Studio Instance 1 is native debugger and uses Unity or your C# program as a Host program, and you attach to the Host program from another Visual Studio Instance.

Comment: you do not need to SCREAM any time you want to highlight stuff. Use italic or bold works better... Just saying because it is annoying to see you scream even in comments...

Comment: It's an old habit like in when you always work with legalese to highlight stuff and important sentences, you use caps-lock...

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me.  The code generates a Unity-managed application crash.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to call

```
System.Environment.FailFast("Error happened")
```

Comment: Worked and has the benefit of being the intended method provided by system library.

Comment: Worked for testing crashing an ASP.NET Core application as well (most of the higher rated options didn't seem to do the trick) - thanks!

Comment: This will put exception details in the Event Log, possibly being reported to Microsoft via Windows Error Reporting (WER). Maybe desired, maybe not.

Answer (score 6):

A surefire way to do it is as follows:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ignored => 
{
   throw new Exception();
}));
```

All the others can be handled by the top level ApplicationDomain.OnUnhandledException and the like.

This one will kill it dead (assuming .NET 2.0+, and not using 'legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx).

Comment: It seems unity3d application ignore the exception directly(not handle it like others), and has no any feedback.

Comment: If you want even less code...  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ignored => throw new Exception());

Comment: Even less `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => throw new Exception());`

Comment: Note that Unity3d will log this exception as long as `UnityEngineApplication.logMessageReceivedThreaded` is used (rather than `logMessageReceived`)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers crashed my app the way I was looking for. So here is the approach that worked for me.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object p = 0;
        IntPtr pnt = (IntPtr)0x123456789;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(p, pnt, false);
    }
```

Comment: Crash is not guaranteed using this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void Loop()
  {
      Loop();
  }
  //call this
  Loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a code in earlier unity versions like

```
Application.commitSuicide(number Input);
```

Now it is replaced by

```
Application.ForceCrash(number input);
```

Till this point, I dont know what different numbers do in number input, but for me,

```
Application.ForceCrash(1);
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

you could also divide by zero,

```
z = 0; 
int divide = 1 / x;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int[] x = {0};
 int blah = x[2];
```

will cause an exception just as well

Comment: sorry,I have try throwing an exception, but that doesn't crash my application

Comment: sorry, I lost something: I use Unity3d, and it handles all exceptions, just show me the exceptions in the output file. thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's easy enough to reproduce if you try to transform a null game object. For example, like this:

```
public static GameObject gameObjectCrash;
public void GenerateCrash()
{
    gameObjectCrash.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use below code to close the application.

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

Exit needs a parameter called exitcode. If exitcode=0 means there was no error. Supply a non-zero exit code to to reflect an error.

Comment: This is CLOSING, not a Crash